# How to replace all instances of words from the div(could be nested) and the words to be replace will be based from a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

i want my web page to display different languages so i want to create a function that replaces all the words that is present in a json file (en.json for english)

i currently have a code that replaces the word but i want all the word that is present in the json file

html

```
<div class="localize">
        <div>fall back menu</div>
        <div>fall back messages</div>
        <div>fall back messages</div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".localize *").contents().each(function() {
      if(this.nodeType==3){
         this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/メニュースペル/g, 'messsadaages')
      }
   });

})
```

output:

```
fall back メニュースペル
fall back messsages
fall back messsages
```

i want the words to be compare should come from the json file

my json file sample would be:

```
{
   "menu" : "メニュースペル",
   "home" : "うちに",
   "log out" "ログアウト"
}
```

i already use localized.js library but it replaces the words after the page is finish rendered (its obvious and can be seen by user)

Comment: Sorry if I ask... but change the JSON file before loading the page? Like in your translation folder you'll have ENGLISH_TRANSLATION.JSON, CHINESE_TRANSLATION.JSON and so on... and you have to load the right one, so the page is rendered on the fly

Comment: sorry the json file will be static, sorry my mistake a have diffrent reference for the example and the json, try to edit it thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
var words = {
  "menu": "メニュースペル",
  "home": "うちに",
  "log out":"ログアウト"
};

var s = $('.localize').html();

for (var property in words) {
    s = s.split(property).join(words[property])
}
$('.localize').html(s)
```

**demo**

```js
var words = {
  "menu": "メニュースペル",
  "home": "うちに",
  "log out":"ログアウト"
};

var s = $('.localize').html();

for (var property in words) {
    s = s.split(property).join(words[property])
}
$('.localize').html(s)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="localize">
  <div>fall back messages</div>
  <div>fall back messages</div>
  <div>fall back menu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @coriano35 No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all your words by following way

```js
var traslations = {
   "menu" : "メニュースペル",
   "home" : "うちに",
   "log out": "ログアウト"
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".localize *").contents().each(function() {
      if(this.nodeType==3) {
        var searchReg = new RegExp(Object.keys(traslations).join("|"), "gi");
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(/menu|home|log out/,function(matched) {
      return traslations[matched];
     });
   }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="localize">
        <div>fall back menu</div>
        <div>fall back home</div>
        <div>fall back log out</div>
</div>
```